# Redirect to the previous page in MVC2 with the parameters that were used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, redirect

In the application, a user types an Id and gets a table with details.
In this table the user can choose to delete an item.
In order to delete an item, I call a controller with the unwanted id. For example: `http://localhost:12345/DeleteItem/{id}`

After that, I would like to redirect the user back to the initial table (without the deleted line) so I want to redirect the person back, and provide the Id, to basically reload the page.

I know that in order to redirect the user back I need to use:
 `return new RedirectResult(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());`

But how can I pass the id?

This is what my program expect to get:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, int? page)
        {
            //some code
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use TempData. thus your action will contain code like follows:

```
var url=string.Format("{0}?id={1}",Request.UrlReferrer,id);
return new RedirectResult(url);

 public ActionResult Index(string id, int? page)
    {
        //some code
    }
```

or

you can always use TempData. thus your action will contain code like follows:

```
TempData["RedirectId"]=id;
return new RedirectResult(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

Comment: I thought about the second option you suggested, but it mess things up in some cases.. Can you please explain a bit more about option #1? how do you later use the TempData["RedirectId"]?

Comment: var id=TempData["RedirectId"]

Comment: I meant, where do you put it? When you want to use it

Comment: I realised that you probably want to not change your action signature and updated the answer accordingly. Basically I am building the queryString

Comment: Eventually I did it with the TempData["RedirectId"], Inside the Index I checked if TempData["RedirectId"] has value, and used it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool.. I was not sure if you wanted to change the actions signature